# Dynamically change css attribute on $.Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I open the dialog by clicking on some button.

```
function startUpload() {
        $.Dialog({
            'title': 'title',
            'content': $('#uploadDialog').html(),
            'draggable': false,
            'overlay': false,
            'closeButton': true,
            'buttonsAlign': 'right',
            'keepOpened': true,
            'position': {
                'zone': 'center'
            },
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Dialog is a partial view.

```
<div id="uploadDialog" class="no-display">
    @Html.Partial("_UploadInfoFilterDialog", @Model)
</div>
```

On the partial view there is a div

```
<div id ="errorDiv" style="display: none">Error message</div>
```

and I want to show it on some event.

```
$("#errorDiv").show();
```

The attribute changes but content of the dialog doesn`t update. I think problem is in dialog, because on main view it works fine. 
I tried $("#errorDiv").html(); too.

How to show errorDiv on dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a dialog window like this copies html from $('#uploadDialog').
So, when I try to find an element like $("#errorDiv"), it returns the first instance of $('#uploadDialog') which is hidden on tha main view (not on dialog).

I should find element like $("#dialogBox #errorDiv") where #dialogBox is root element of #uploadDialog.